# Why using [a] and not [an] in "a user interface is like a joke. If you have to explain it, it's not that good"

Tags: pronunciation

I've found this phrase across the internet and [everywhere](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=A%20user%20interface%20is%20like%20a%20joke.%20If%20you%20have%20to%20explain%20it,%20it%27s%20not%20that%20good&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1350&bih=655&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPh66KzPXLAhUJ-GMKHam8AEwQ_AUIBigB) they use "**A** user interface" instead of "**An** user interface".

Is it an error that has been propagated or is it correct? If it's correct, why?

Comment: Because _spelling_ is not the reason why we use _an_ it's the pronunciation. _Hour_ for example we say _an hour_ because _h_ is silent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the use of *a* or *an* is based on the pronunciation, not the spelling.  Since *usage* is pronounced with the *y* sound (which does not count as a vowel), most people would put *a* before it. It goes both ways, though.  The *h* in *honor* is silent, so it would be *an* honor.  Many years ago, any word that started with an *h* would have *an* before it.  For example, *an* humble home.  That isn't common in modern times, though.